# smartd rule does not work

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, smartctl

I have an issue with smartd.
I've studied its man page, and then I've set the SMART daemon to run long test of the hard disks two times a month and alert to the specified mail address in case of faults such as high temperature. Those rules are following:

```
/dev/sda -a -p -W 2,37,42 -s L/../(28|12)/../01 -m mail@addr.com -M daily
/dev/sdb -a -p -W 2,37,42 -s L/../(29|13)/../01 -m mail@addr.com -M daily
```

It turned out, that those rules do not really work: the tests do not run. To me, the rules look completely legitimate. What am I doing wrong?